# show a page inside a window in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, window, frame

I have a tabcontrol in my window, inside each tabitem I want to have a different page.
I can achieve this by making a Frame inside the TabItem and in the behind code use for example:

```
frame1.Content = new Pages.MyPage()
```

How can I do the same thing in XAML?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<TabItem>
  <Frame Source="MyPage.xaml" />
</TabItem>
```

Comment: hah... that simple. Thanks. It won't show up in the designer though. Maybe it's not possible?

Comment: @steini: I dont't know. I never use designer :)

Answer (score 0):

you probably don't need the frame. Something like this should work.

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem>
    <MyPage Name=frame1 />
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem>
    <MyPage Name=frame2 />
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

If you want the frame just do:

```
<TabItem>
  <Frame>
    <MyPage Name=frame1 />
  </Frame>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: The first solution results in an InvalidOperationException: "page can only have window or frame as a parent". The second one, "Frame does not support direct content".

Comment: Does MyPage extends UserControl? If not, which class does it extend?

Comment: I don't know. It's just a normal page. How would I know that?

Comment: steini: <Frame><Frame.Content><MyPage/></Frame.Content></Frame>