# How to get Frame in the Page?

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

In my `Window`, has a Frame

This `Frame` is navigating a `Page` `Login.xaml`, so I need when login is sucessful, Frame navigate for other Page, `Main.xaml`

How can I do for get this Frame in my `Login` `Page`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to contruct the MainPage and place it into the Content property of the Frame.

```
Frame1.Content = new MainPage();
```

See something simular: [show a page inside a window in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477871/show-a-page-inside-a-window-in-xaml)

Here's some more info about navigation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: How can I do for get Frame1 in the MainPage for set next page?